# Java: Apache poi Module org.slf4j not found, required by org.apache.poi.poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have added all the jars for apache poi into the module path for this project but anytime I try to use it I get the error

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.slf4j not found, required by org.apache.poi.poi

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class DataTesting { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String excelFilePath = "H:\\exceltest\\test1.xlsx";
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
         
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
         
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
             
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                 
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                    case NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                }
                System.out.print(" - ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
         
        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

Comment: Share the error logs

Comment: its not showing in the error log the last entry is from 5 days ago